# Execution Context Key NULL in JobExecutionListenerSupport

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using the below `ItemWriteListener` to store id values as they are encountered.
I am aware there are `Step` and `Job` contexts in spring, so I am trying to use the **Job** context to store and retreive values.

```
@JobScope
@Component
public class JobWriteNotificationListener implements ItemWriteListener<Retailer> {
    private ExecutionContext context;

    public JobWriteNotificationListener(StepExecution context) {
        this.context = context.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        if (!this.context.containsKey(RETAILER_ID_KEY))
            this.context.put(RETAILER_ID_KEY, new HashSet<Integer>());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Set<Integer> get() {
        return (Set<Integer>) this.context.get(RETAILER_ID_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterWrite(List<? extends Retailer> list) {
        Set<Integer> set = get();
        list.forEach(id -> set.add(id.getId()));
    }
}
```

I am attempting to retreive these values in the `afterJob` listener.

```
@JobScope
@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JobCompletionNotificationListener(
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Set<Integer> added = (Set<Integer>) jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get(RETAILER_ID_KEY);
        if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            log.info("job completed {} :: added {}", jobExecution.getStatus(), added.size());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the `afterJob` method, `jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get(RETAILER_ID_KEY)` is throwing a null reference exception.

From what I can see I am using the **Job** context for both?

Comment: Is it an option for you to add those IDs in the writer directly without using a listener? I think it is easier to get access to the stepExecution in the writer than in the writerListener (See example in https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create @Component in @JobScope, and inject it into each component.
It will be shared in the scope.